# Derivative of product of matrix function and constant scalar:$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf{x}}\left[ \left\{ \bf{B}(\bf{x}) \right\}^T \bf{a} \right]$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

$$
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
$$

Let $\mb{B}(\mb{x})$ be a matrix ($m \times n$) which is a function of vector $\mb{x}$ ($n$ elements), and let $\mb{a}$ be a constant column vector ($m$ elements). I want to compute the derivative

$$
\begin{align}
\phantom{{}={}} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \mb{x}}\left[ \left\{ \mb{B}(\mb{x})
\right\}^T \mb{a} \right] \right)
\end{align}.
$$

This is a derivative of a vector with respect to a vector which yields a matrix (in the form of a Jacobian matrix).

However, there is no compact, matrix-based notation for this matrix. I only managed to provide a solution for the *rows* of the matrix:

$$
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \mb{x}}\left[ \left\{ \mb{B}(\mb{x})
\right\}^T \mb{a} \right] \right)_{i,*} \nonumber \\
%====================
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mb{x}}\left( \left[ \mb{B}(\mb{x})
\right]^T \mb{a} \right)_{i}\\
%====================
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mb{x}}\left( \left[ \mb{b}_{i}(\mb{x})
\right]^T \mb{a} \right)\\
%====================
& = \mb{a}^T \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \mb{x}}\mb{b}_{i}(\mb{x})
\right).
\end{align}
$$

where  $\mb{b}_i$ is the column vector $i$ of $\mb{B}$.

Is there some compact matrix notation for the result? I thought of some operator similar to the Kronecker product. It would be even better if something would be known about the properties of such an operator (as I have to further explore such matrices). Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\G{\grad{c}{x}}
$Assume that one knows how to calculate the component-wise matrix-valued gradients
$$G_k = \grad{B}{x_k}\;\in\bbR{m\times n}$$
and is tasked with calculating the gradient of the vector
$$c = B^Ta$$
The component-wise calculation is straightforward
$$\eqalign{
\grad{c}{x_k} &= G_k^Ta \\
}$$
Multiply by the $\{e_k\in\bbR n\}$ standard basis vectors
and sum to recover an expression for the full gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{c}{x} &= \LR{\sum_{k=1}^n G_k^T\,ae_k^T}
\;\in\bbR{n\times n} \\
}$$
That's about as much as one can say about the matter. However, if you tell us more about the functional dependence of $B(x),\,$
then perhaps a simpler expression can be found.

For example:

$\quad$if $B=xy^T,\;$ then $\G=ya^T$

$\quad$if $B=\Diag{x},\;$ then $\G=\Diag{a}$

$\quad$if $B=Mxx^TN,\;$ then $\G=\LR{a^TMx}N^T + N^Txa^TM$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your derivation takes the element-wise way and is more general since it doesn't assume that the column vectors of $B$ are explicitly known. However, as far as I can see, the result is the same as mine, is that correct? In my case, $B$ is the Jacobian of some (arbitrary) vector-valued function $g$ with respect to $x$. Is there something that could be said about this special case?

Comment: @Ralf Your result is also an element-wise approach; summing it over the standard basis yields $$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = \sum_{i=1}^n e_ia^T\frac{\partial b_i}{\partial x}$$ Unfortunately, the fact that $B$ is the Jacobian of an _**arbitrary**_ function is not enough to simplify the expressions. That would require a particular function to be specified.

Comment: You are right about the element-wise approach. I also agree that there's no closed-form matrix description, so my question is answered. Thanks a lot again! By the way, that was my application: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4269130/702757